# To terminate the running application in python script

Tags: python

I am writing a simple python script to run and close one `flatpak` application. 
I am triggering `gedit` application using `flatpak` command but having a hard time to figure out how to quit the application from script itself. Since once the application launches, python scripts waits for the application to terminate and then to exit.

Code:

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    os.system("flatpak run org.gnome.gedit/x86_64/stable")
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In above code I tried `sys.exit()`, but it doesn't work as it waits for the application to terminate.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("flatpak run org.gnome.gedit/x86_64/stable")
p.terminate()
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) you can find more information about this

Comment: throwing error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flatpak run org.gnome.gedit/x86_64/stable'. Inside " " is the command that needs to be run on terminal in order to run flatpak application.

Comment: instead of `flatpak` assign absloute path for example `/bin/flatpak` or every path it has.If you don't know where it is you can find it with `whereis flatpak`